# Regex for extracting phone numbers

Tags: java, regex

I have following requirements:

Number (in sequence or seperated by **hyphen** or **space**)

Can have **hyphen -** in between [optional]

Can have **space** in between [optional]

Can have **open braces (** and **closing brace )** [optional]

Can have **plus +** at the beginning. [optional]

Right now, i'm using ***(^| )[0-9.() -+]{5,}( |$)***

Sample text:

> CONTACT Asia:  (11) 6530-6596-3242, +9145465465465  (011)4420717696024  +1 212-904-2860

Comment: I can recommend http://www.rubular.com/ as a "workbench" to develop and test your regular expression. Also contains a reference.

Comment: You should not post real names and email addresses...

Answer (score 0):

Finding phone numbers is a rather hard problem, as different regions have different conventions for their phone numbers. I would suggest [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/), a library developed at Google for that very purpose. The libary contains a method [`findNumbers(CharSequence, String)`](https://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.html#findNumbers(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.String)) that finds phone numbers and returns them in parsed manner.

```
String text = "Call me at +1 425 882-8080 for details.";
RegionCode country = RegionCode.US;
PhoneNumberUtil util = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

// Find the first phone number match:
PhoneNumberMatch m = util.findNumbers(text, country).iterator().next();

// rawString() contains the phone number as it appears in the text.
"+1 425 882-8080".equals(m.rawString());

// start() and end() define the range of the matched subsequence.
CharSequence subsequence = text.subSequence(m.start(), m.end());
"+1 425 882-8080".contentEquals(subsequence);

// number() returns the the same result as PhoneNumberUtil.parse()
// invoked on rawString().
util.parse(m.rawString(), country).equals(m.number());
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably wont work in every situation but you should have more input rules for phone number, but can you give this a try: `[0-9\(\+]+[0-9\)\-]+[, ]?`